# Hardware setup for LED with external power supply

Tags: hardware, power-supply, led

I am looking for help to use a raspberry pi 3 as a multiple LED switcher.
The setup should be:

- 6 LEDs at 3W, 9.6V and 300mA (each!)
- a external power supply for the LEDs
- a breadboard to put everything together
- raspberry pi 3 ofc
- probably some resistors/transistors (?)

I am pretty new to this and do not know how to connect things the right way. My plan is to connect it like this:

```
Vcc --- LED1 --- GND (on the GPIO Pins)
             \-- GND (on external power supply)


Vcc --- LED2 --- GND (on the GPIO Pins)
             \-- GND (on external power supply)
```

And so on. Is this the right way to go? Can i control the LEDs one by one separately? What Vcc do i need in terms of watt, volt and ampere?

Thank you for helping!

Edit:

Okay, so this is the way solved my project. I ll write it down so interested people can benefit (hopfully). If someone wants to give further advice, i am happy to read them for knowledge!

I used six transistors, one external power supply for the six 9V LEDs (they have a resistor internally) and the Raspberry Pi with six GPIO 2 to 7 pins.

Connected the power supply to phase and ground on a breadboard, set up the LEDs in parallel each followed by a transistor. Connected the Raspberry Pi GPIO to the transistor and from there to ground. When i set one GPIO.HIGH the transistor switches and the LED lights up. Also dimming works pretty well.

All the best!